# Silverstripe: ajax search only shows ids

Tags: backend, silverstripe

I've got an Event content type that has coupled events. The content type does not have a title. I've defined a searchable_fields private static:

```
private static $searchable_fields = array(
    'ProjectNumber',
    'EventDate'             => 'PartialMatch',
    'TicketCode'            => 'PartialMatch',
    "Package.Title"         => 'PartialMatch',
);
```

Searching in the field (see attachment) is working, but I only see the ID, whcih is, to say the least, less than optimal :-). Does anyone know how to override the system in such a way that it shows the TicketCode or EventDate?

[image: Dropdown example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter` displays the `$Title` of the result. If you don't have `Title` or `Name` field, this defaults to `#$ID`, as you're seeing.

You can either add a `getTitle` method to your class that returns what you want, or change what gets returned by the component.

You'd do this using something like:

```
$config->getComponentByType('GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter')->setResultsFormat('$TicketCode - $EventDate.Nice');
```

Comment: Thanks! In the end I used the getTitle method.

Answer (score 0):

Define the fields you'd like to display in the GridField using:

```
private static $summary_fields = array(
    'TicketCode',
    'EventDate'
);
```

Documentation here: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/dataobject#summary-fields